# How to fix unix `join` command inserting ^M between join columns? -Unix

Tags: osx, join

I am a novice programmer. I am using unix's `join` command to self-join couple long files together.

```
join -j30 test test2
col1 col2 ... col30    col1 col2 ... col30
A    B        ZZZ   ^M A    B        ZZZ
```

I am getting this `^M` character in my output.

Why is it there? and How would I remove it?

EDIT:
Below is a screenshot of my part of my output

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is `join` and not that one of the input files has `CR` in it?

Comment: How would I go about checking if it has a `CR` (assuming that means Carriage Return; excuse my lack of knowledge)? There are `\n` characters in the original file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ^M means you are bringing over/editing file in Windows.

Use the `dos2unix` command over the files to convert them to Unix text mode.

DOS uses carriage return and line feed "\r\n" as a line ending, while Unix uses just line feed "\n". The ^M are a visual representation of the "extra" \r characters.

To install the `dos2unix` command, do (on Debian-based distros):

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

or in a Mac (MacPorts):

```
sudo port install dos2unix
```

Alternatively, you can also do it with sed as in:

```
sed 's/\r$//' dosfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```

Comment: Does the `dos2unix` command come standard to unix machines? I am getting `command not found`

Comment: added to the answer.

Comment: I am on a MacOS and can use `apt-get`. I used your `sed` command and it does not remove the `^M` characters.

Comment: @NicholasHayden and now this version of sed? Have you Macports, fink, or anything similar?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. The only package manger I have is `conda` but that more for `python.` But I think the tr option may work. I am playing around with it in combination with `od -bc` to see if it is removing. But the problem is `\r\n` characters from the original file.

Comment: @NicholasHayden For people that use Mac for development, I second having MacPorts, fink or HomeBrew to install BSD port packages ported to MacOS.

Comment: Will do, any recommendations?

Comment: @NicholasHayden Myself I prefer MacPorts, others might have a different opinion...MacPorts has more packages, and is more stable.

Answer (score 1):

`join(1)` (at least the version I'm using) does not add `^M` or carriage returns to joined files; `join` will however happily copy `^M` along. A hex viewer plus some test cases can show what is going on:

```
$ echo "1 a" > test1
$ echo "1 b" > test2
$ join test1 test2 | od -bc
0000000   061 040 141 040 142 012                                        
           1       a       b  \n                                        
0000006
$
```

And a test case where there are `^M` in the input files:

```
$ perl -E "say qq(1 a\r)" > test1
$ perl -E "say qq(1 b\r)" > test2
$ join test1 test2 | od -bc
0000000   061 040 141 015 040 142 015 012                                
           1       a  \r       b  \r  \n                                
0000010
$
```

There are various ways to correct the input files, besides `dos2unix` one could also use `tr` (though this would be a terrible idea if the file uses the ancient MacOS tradition of `\r` as a line delimiter):

```
$ od -bc test1
0000000   061 040 141 015 012                                            
           1       a  \r  \n                                            
0000005
$ tr -d '\r' < test1 > foo
$ mv foo test1
$ od -bc test1            
0000000   061 040 141 012                                                
           1       a  \n                                                
0000004
$
```

Comment: I did not propose `tr` as sed is a bit more cleaner, defining only to delete the carriage return at the end of the file.